# Using .next() to find and display next div

Tags: jquery

I have some divs and spans that are created dynamically with PHP. When the spans are clicked, I would like the next "add player" div to slide down.

I want to use

```
$(document).on('click','.plus',function(){
    $(this).find('#add_player').slideToggle();
});
```

but I can't do that without the "add player" div being inside the span tag... which I don't want.

So next I tried:

```
$(document).on('click','.plus',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().next('#add_player').slideToggle();
});
```

and that did not work either.

```
<div id="roster">

    <div>

        <span class="plus">+</span>

        <div id="add_player">

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Am I structuring the HTML correctly?

Comment: To answer your last question: No, ID's need to be unique so you should probably use a class for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `siblings()`

```
$(document).on('click', '.plus', function() {
    $(this).siblings('#add_player').slideToggle();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beFt7/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Alternative you can go this way:

```
$(document).on('click','.plus',function(){
    $(this).next("div").slideToggle();
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('click','.plus',function(){
        $(this).next("#add_player").slideToggle();
    });
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ELYpf/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The value of ID is unique value of DOM so you can directly user. this will 100%

```
$('#add_player').slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

.find() only returns the elements within the selector, in this case as you stated, the div would have to be inside of the span tag.  Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','.plus',function(){
    $('#add_player').slideToggle();
});
```